# Compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the finite intersection property

Tags: compactness

Show that a set $K ⊂ \mathbb{R}^n$
is compact if and only if every family of closed subsets of K having the finite
intersection property has nonempty intersection.
I was able to prove one side (That if $K$ is compact then every family of closed subsets of $K$ having the finite
intersection property has nonempty intersection), but something doesn't work in the other direction.

Our definition of compact set is that for every open cover $\{F_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ there exists a finite subcover such that $K\subset\bigcup_{i\in J}F_{i}$ where $J\subset I$ is a finite subset of indices.

I tried using De - Morgan, but that fact that $K\subset\bigcup_{i\in J}F_{i}$ and not $K=\bigcup_{i\in J}F_{i}$ got me stuck.

Comment: But $K=\bigcup_{i\in J}(F_i\cap K)$, where each $F_i\cap K$ is open *in $K$*.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net No because here $K^{c} \neq \emptyset$

Comment: @Thorgott Im just now starting topology, how can you tell $F_{i}\cap K$ is open?

Comment: That's the definition of the subspace topology on $K$: open sets in $K$ are precisely the intersections of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $K$.

Comment: @GalBenAyun Just use the [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology)!

Comment: @Thorgott But I still don't understand how you can deduce that $F_{i}$ open $\rightarrow F_{i}\cap K$ without any assumptions about K.

Comment: It's true by definition for any reasonable definition. If you don't agree, tell me how you define the open/closed subsets of $K$.